# New post from database

Tags: custom-post-types, mysql

I have data stored in DB (mysql)
I want to creat new post for each row 
I have created custom post type with custom fields

Beside xml rpc is there any other way.

Cheers

Comment: Yes sure you can do some `MySQL query` using [`$wpdb Object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and then in `foreach() loop` use [`wp_insert_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [`add_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) to add all those rows in your post table.

Comment: @MohammadMursaleen you should write that up into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With few lines of code you can transfer your data from your custom table to post table.

1. Do some `MySQL query` using [$wpdb Object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to get data from your custom table.
2. And then in [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop use [`wp_insert_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) and [`add_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) to add all those rows in your post table.

And you are Done!